# JS ES6 imports intellisense not working in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

How to make ES6 imports intellisense work in VS Code?
Variable 'cl' expected to be type of 'MyClass', but it is type of 'any'.
[image: ES6 imports intellisense not working in VS Code]

Comment: Related issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26338

Comment: @ikhvjs the same issue in VS 2021. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please check the issue above. Also, you may just use some bundle builder such as `parcel` and `webpack` instead?